# How to hide an item from a list?

Tags: python

Not sure how if I'm asking this right but I want to send a list to a function but I want to exclude specific items that I'm sending. I know for a list I can use .remove to remove a item but it appears to remove it from the actual list which is not what I want.  I want to send a list to a function and exclude a specific list item.

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
def stuff(list):
    #do something
    pass

a = ["cat", "dog", "pig", "horse"]

stuff(a.remove("dog"))
```

in this case, "dog" is removed from the list(a) but what I really want is to send ["cat", "pig", "horse"] to the function.

Is it possible to exclude it? I was thinking of making a temp list that I create each time but was curious if there was a simpler way.

Comment: is it the value 2 you want removed, or whatever object is second in the list?

Comment: in other words, does `[5, 4, 3, 2]` become `[5, 3, 2]` or `[5, 4, 3]`?

Comment: You can reshape the list based on your conditions inside the function

Comment: @PaulH I'm sorry, your right, I want the value 2 removed when I Sent it..not the second item.

Comment: make a new list without 2, probably by list comprehension, but I would recommend filter

Comment: why you donst swap this item with the last item in the list and send the list with length -1 to you function then swap again after function return. this approach is right only if the order is not issue.

Comment: I updated the question to add animals instead of numbers to make it less confusing thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Lostsoul your edit contradicts your comment above. It seems like you want remove the second item, no mater what it is. Is that correct?

Comment: @PaulH I do not want to remove the second item. I want to remove a specific value in the list regardless of it's location  in the list.

Comment: Are you asking how to filter items from a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```py
stuff(list(filter(lambda x: x != 2, a))
```

> The filter() method filters the given sequence with the help of a function that tests each element in the sequence to be true or not.
> [filter() in python - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filter-in-python/#:%7E:text=OpenCV%20and%20OCR-,filter()%20in%20python,a%20sequence%20true%20or%20not.)